# Opening a word document on clients PC, through a PHP application

Tags: php

I am developing a web application in PHP as a replacement of Microsoft Access based application for a company.

In old access application in their database they were storing a link to a word document, which further links to other documents. Now in access form they are showing that link, when click on that link they can open the word document from a common folder in a network PC and make any changes the that file (pretty easy for user).

Is there any way to do the same through the web-based application?

---

**What if I just move the common folder in my www directory?**

In that case they can open the file easily, but if they have to make any change they have to download the file on their PC, and the changes will be done to their local file not in the file that is on server. So they need to move file to server back or ask network admin for moving the file back to the server

---

**What if I keep common folder in a network PC it self and try to access it form there?**

Just by clicking I can’t open a file form client’s or any other network PC. For this when click on the link I have to open & read file through PHP on web server. Using any document to PDF converter, I have to convert the file format and then open it in browser. Here the problem are,

- Still I can’t make changes in file and
- I have to fix about the format that I might need to convert in PDF.
- I am not sure how the other documents that are linked to the main document will work.

Comment: if this is a company, i would suggest to get someone who knows what he/she is doing

Comment: Is php an absolute requirement? SharePoint Foundation server is free (if you have a windows server in-house) and does what you want.

Comment: What about just linking to the network share? Browsers can offer paths to local files, that works.

Comment: Yes, we need to give this feature through PHP application @ agrothe

Comment: Through PHP I can access only the files that are in web server. Accessing file on client's PC or network through a web application is considered as Security threat so inking to the network share is not working. I can write a php scritp which will copy the file form given path to web server and open it from their. But as the documents contains further more link to other documents this approch will also not work. Any ways thanks for your prompt response

Comment: If this is a company, or for future suggestion: "don't waste your Time, and Effort to create a desktop Application. Put, and try to make a Device interdependent Applications. I don't know how long desktop PC's alive, but I think the days are come out of it (desk Apps)." For storage your data (and I can bet with you, that database Application's need much of this). But this is not a must to do, it is a Hint from me to you.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways of doing this: (a) let the user download it from your web application, either statically (stored on the web server) or dynamically (processed in PHP or even built in real-time).

Or, (b) use a file link to a known location on the user's disk, such as file://C:/mydoc.doc.

Addendum - if you want to write to the file in your web app, but also have the user open the same copy, use (b) rather than (a). This presumes that the location of the file is available through a local or network path.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response. The code that I put in my PHP file is print("<a href=\"file:///g:/Doc/Lampson.doc\">Vew System Info</a>") but no success as it will try to look into G: drive of the user...

Comment: Right, in light of your comment on the question, having a file:// reference is not going to help you. The easiest way (for the developer) is to have an upload control, and require the user to upload it every time they change it. However that is a pain for them. Alternatively (c) you could consider a Flash utility in your website with special permissions to access/write to the local hard-disc (subject to you being sure this is safe to do).